# A Latin text with dependency tree

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, resource-request

I am looking for a Latin text that has word by word English translation and explanation. I mean after the translation, it explains that this word has ablative case and that has nominative or this verb has perfect tense and that has imperfect and all related explanations. Something like **[dependency grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_grammar)**.
Is there any?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try "Completely Parsed Cicero" by Maclardy. It´s on Amazon.

There is: "Caeser Completely Parsed" by James B. Finch.

Back in May, I couldn't find this though knew it existed. Price fluctuates between £30-94--beware.

Alternatively, it's on the net, for free: "archive.org/details/CommentariesOnTheGallicWarCaeserCompletelyParsedBook1"

There is: "Translating Pliny's Letters About Vesuvius part 3" on site: "quemdixerechaos.com/2012/11/28/translatingplinypt3"

Comment: It is exactly what I want

Comment: The link to Caesar is https://archive.org/details/CommentariesOnTheGallicWarCaesarCompletelyParsedBookI with I, not 1.

Answer (score 8):

There is a project called [The Ancient Greek and Latin Dependency Treebank](https://perseusdl.github.io/treebank_data/), which has done dependency trees for some Greek and Latin texts. There is a document explaining the project [here](http://people.ischool.berkeley.edu/~dbamman/pubs/pdf/latech2011.pdf). It seems it does not contain English translations, but if you combine their work with a dictionary, or an English translation of the text, you might get further.

There are three similar projects listed [here](https://universaldependencies.org/).

All these projects are open-source and community based, so you could suggest the option of translation or contribute with it yourself.

Notice however that, as far as I know, it is not always possible to do word-by-word translations from Latin to English. Also, the word order in English might not correspond to that in Latin (which has no compulsory order). So maybe, what you are after doesn't really exist (and wouldn't be totally helpful either).

Comment: Regardless of the meaning of sentence after word by word translation, it is useful to know which literal or maybe metaphorical meaning of each word is signified in a sentence.

Answer (score 3):

There is [Index Thomisticus](https://uni-tuebingen.de/fakultaeten/philosophische-fakultaet/fachbereiche/neuphilologie/seminar-fuer-sprachwissenschaft/arbeitsbereiche/allg-sprachwissenschaft-computerlinguistik/ressourcen/corpora/index-thomisticus-baumbank.html), a treebank consisting of work of Thomas Aquinas. It is a free resource under a Creative Commons licence.